# A question about "spike upwards"

Tags: word-usage

My dictionary defines the word spike as "if the number or rate of something spikes, it increases quickly and by a large amount." So I understand that if you said "inflation spiked upward," you would be saying "inflation rose upward sharply," which would be redandunt. However, if I google for "spiked upward," I find numerous examples (some of them written by authoritative sources) using this. Does this mean that "spike upward" does not have to be avoided? I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: It's 'redundant' `:)`

Comment: You seem to be equating redundancy with something that's bad. But something that's redundant isn't always without value. Saying that you are *absolutely sure* is redundant, yet it's an expression that's still used and that makes sense.

Comment: Note that a graph can spike downwards.

Comment: People say "fall down" all the time. I have never seen anything fall _up_.

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's not redundant in many contexts, a spike in data can be in either direction. This is true in stock prices for example and a 'spike' is defined by [this website](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/spike.asp) as **a comparatively large upward or downward movement of a price in a short period of time**. It would certainly be necessary to include 'upward' or 'downward' in any discussion of a spike in stock prices and, I would say, in many other fields as well.

Comment: @BoldBen I was talking about the spelling

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The September 15, 2016, issue of The Economist carried a short article entitled “The human toll of the Philippines’ war on drugs  Extrajudicial killings have spiked since the election of Rodrigo Duterte,” which describes a change that occurred during the period of about five months. When the article was written, there wasn’t probably any sign that “extrajudicial killings” would rapidly decline in the immediate future. Also, It didn't say "spiked upward." Do you think the magazine’s use of “spiked” was not appropriate for these reasons?

Comment: @Cascabel - https://books.google.com/books?id=VXPCJY9tFkMC&pg=PA99&dq=%22fall+up+the+stairs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8hc-D_p7kAhU8FTQIHXh5D2IQ6AEwBHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fall%20up%20the%20stairs%22&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks After posting that comment, I later thought about _dust_, and that definitely falls up sometimes.;-)

Comment: @NigelJ - So what are the things on the bottom of golf shoes?

Comment: @NigelJ - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downward+spike&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdownward%20spike%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdownward%20spike%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks ...at Trump's Mar-a -Lago? Maybe it was pieces of shit? He loves walking across the backs of lesser beings, especially when they used to lick his shoes.

Comment: A spike is a sharp rise followed by a sharp fall, or vice versa. It is not simply a rise or a fall. The question misses this point (no pun intended) so is ill-posed and only answerable with opinions and confused discussion. I have therefore voted to close it.